# Why I get the structure of the Json instead of just the value?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I think that already understand how to obtain the Json data with the differents 
parenthesis of this [Json](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=10.114122,%20-84.461641&destinations=10.088728,-84.488104&mode=driving). With my code, I obtain the data that I need but I notice two things.

1) Why I cant especify that I need the text value of the distance by getText(), because when I write the code just let me be in getElements().

2) Why if I show the value of the distance, It give me all the structure all the Json starting in Elements for example: [Elements{distance=Distance{text='5.6km'}}]  instead of just 5.6Km

The same occur with duration!

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                            .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com")
                                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                            .build();

                                    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

                                    Call<Feed> call = apiInterface.getData();

                                    call.enqueue(new Callback<Feed>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(Call<Feed> call, Response<Feed> response) {

                                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Server Response: "+response.toString());
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: received information: "+ response.body().toString());

                                            ArrayList<Rows> rowsList = response.body().getRows();
                                            ArrayList<String> destination_addresses_list = response.body().getDestination_addresses();

                                            for (int i=0; i<rowsList.size(); i++){



                                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: \n"+
                                                "destination_addresses: "+ destination_addresses_list.get(i)+"\n"+

                                                // this is where I cant specify getElements().getDistance().getText()
                                                "distance"+ rowsList.get(i).getElements()+

                                               //And in this one too!  getElements().getDuration().getText()
                                                "duration"+ rowsList.get(i).getElements());

                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(Call<Feed> call, Throwable t) {

                                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: algo paso: "+ t.getMessage());
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
```

feed class:

```
public class Feed {


@SerializedName("destination_addresses")
@Expose
private ArrayList<String> destination_addresses;

// este contiene cas datos que se pueden separar
@SerializedName("rows")
@Expose
private ArrayList<Rows> rows;


public ArrayList<String> getDestination_addresses() {
    return destination_addresses;
}

public void setDestination_addresses(ArrayList<String> destination_addresses) {
    this.destination_addresses = destination_addresses;
}

public ArrayList<Rows> getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(ArrayList<Rows> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Feed{" +
            "destination_addresses=" + destination_addresses +
            ", rows=" + rows +
            '}';
}
}
```

Rows class

```
public class Rows {

@SerializedName("elements")
@Expose
private ArrayList<Elements> elements;

public ArrayList<Elements> getElements() {
    return elements;
}

public void setElements(ArrayList<Elements> elements) {
    this.elements = elements;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Rows{" +
            "elements=" + elements +
            '}';
}
}
```

Elements class

```
public class Elements {

@SerializedName("distance")
@Expose
private Distance distance;


@SerializedName("duration")
@Expose
private Duration duration;


public Distance getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(Distance distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}



public Duration getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Elements{" +
            "distance=" + distance +
          //  ", duration=" + duration +
            '}';
}
}
```

Distance class

```
public class Distance {

@SerializedName("text")
@Expose
private String text;


public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Distance{" +
            "text='" + text + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Duration class

```
public class Duration {


@SerializedName("text")
@Expose
private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Duration{" +
            "text='" + text + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElements().` return an array list of elements so you can't just say

```
getElements().getDuration().getText()
```

you have to specify the position of the element you trying to access in your json it's only one element so the correct format is

```
getElements().get(0).getDuration().getText()
```

Or you can make a look to get the elements by index if the are more than one

and also if you take loop at your json it return a json array not a json object